# KEYCLOAK - Refresh/update token not working

Tags: angularjs, authentication, token, keycloak

I have single page application that is built using `Angularjs` and integrated with `Keycloak` for ***authentication and authorization***.

I am able to login into my application, get loggedin user roles etc. goes The moment refresh token call, it always returns in my else case, and user logout of the application. Though the token valid time is set very high.

I need to update the token, if user has opened the app. In case of failure or expire token i need to logout the user. `if (refreshed)` always returns false.

Below is the piece of code i am using.

```
var __env = {};

        Object.assign(__env, window.__env);

        var keycloakConfig = {
            "url" : __env.keycloakUrl,
            "realm" : __env.keycloakRealm,
            "clientId" : __env.keycloakClientId,
            "credentials" : {
            "secret" : __env.keycloakSecret
            }
        };
var keycloak = Keycloak(keycloakConfig);
        keycloak.init({
            onLoad : 'login-required'
        }).success(function(authenticated) {
                 if(authenticated){                  
                        keycloak.loadUserInfo().success(function(userInfo) {
                        bootstrapAngular(keycloak, userInfo, roles);
                    });
            }
        });

function bootstrapAngular(keycloak, userInfo, roles) {
        angular.module('myApp').run(
                function($rootScope, $http, $interval, $cookies) {
                    var updateTokenInterval = $interval(function() {
                        // refresh token if it's valid for less then 15 minutes
                    keycloak.updateToken(15).success(
                                function(refreshed) {
                                    if (refreshed) {
                                        $cookies.put('X-Authorization-Token',
                                                keycloak.token);
                                    }else{
                                        $rootScope.logoutApp();
                                    }
                                });
                    }, 600000);
                    updateTokenInterval;
                    $cookies.put('X-Authorization-Token', keycloak.token);

                    $rootScope.logoutApp = function() {
                        $cookies.remove('X-Authorization-Token');
                        $interval.cancel(updateTokenInterval);
                        keycloak.logout();
                    };
    }
}
```

Comment: Got a similar problem, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I couldn't find explained it in the API docs but the `timeout` argument of `keycloak.updateToken()` function is expressed in **seconds**, not in minutes.

So if the *Access Token Lifespan* on server is at the default value of 5 minutes, you should use a value less than 300 seconds.
I learned it doing some experiments.

```
//Update the token when will last less than 3 minutes
keycloak.updateToken(180)
```

Btw I suggest you to use a *Lifespan* longer than 5 minutes for the token.

In your code You never see the token refreshed because the refresh is never triggered in the 15 seconds window in which will work.

Comment: If you ever need to force refresh the token (for example to update the permissions in it) you can use `updateToken(-1)`. Do not abuse this...

Comment: If we request `updateToken` multiple times. Keycloak maintains a queue of these calls and only processes first `updateToken` request. Whenever the response of first `updateToken` is received, It immediately returns it's response for all of the remaining `updateToken` requests in queue.

Answer (score 11):

(refreshed) returns false only if your token is not expired. So you're trying to **refresh the token when it has not yet expired**.

set " Access Token Lifespan " to 1 minute in the **Keycloak realm** you're using,
then
try the following code to check the status of refreshed again

```
keycloak.onTokenExpired = ()=>{
            console.log('expired '+new Date());
            keycloak.updateToken(50).success((refreshed)=>{
                if (refreshed){
                    console.log('refreshed '+new Date());
                }else {
                    console.log('not refreshed '+new Date());
                }
            }).error(() => {
                 console.error('Failed to refresh token '+new Date());
            });
            }
```

Comment: `So you're trying to refresh the token when it has not yet expired` Yeah thats it! Thanky you

Comment: Can you explain what does updateToken min validity param (50 on this case) means? On my case I have WebSocket connection and when token is expired the connection is closed and I retry, retry, retry... So can I say the token ever refreshed correctly and connection was opened?

Comment: If the token expires within minValidity seconds (minValidity is optional, if not specified 5 is used) the token is refreshed. If the session status iframe is enabled, the session status is also checked.

This is what the documentation says

Comment: tokenExpired has to added before keycloak init

Answer (score 4):

I take a look on their sample code:

````
        /**
     * If the token expires within `minValidity` seconds, the token is refreshed.
     * If the session status iframe is enabled, the session status is also
     * checked.
     * @returns A promise to set functions that can be invoked if the token is
     *          still valid, or if the token is no longer valid.
     * @example
     * ```js
     * keycloak.updateToken(5).success(function(refreshed) {
     *   if (refreshed) {
     *     alert('Token was successfully refreshed');
     *   } else {
     *     alert('Token is still valid');
     *   }
     * }).error(function() {
     *   alert('Failed to refresh the token, or the session has expired');
     * });
     */
````

So I think your token is still valid, that's why the updateToken return false.

Answer (score 1):

```
keycloak.onAuthSuccess = function() { alert('authenticated'); }

keycloak.onTokenExpired = function () {
            keycloak.updateToken(5)
            .then(function (refreshed) {
                if (refreshed) {
                    alert('Token refreshed');
                  // write any code you required here
                } else {
                    alert('Token is still valid now');
                }
            }).catch(function () {
                alert('Failed to refresh the token, or the session has expired');
            }); }
            keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).then(function (authenticated) {..... }
```

Comment: How to update keycloak  token when token gets expired in client side JavaScript refer ----https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.adoc

The adapter supports setting callback listeners for certain events. Keep in mind that these (onTokenExpired,  onAuthSuccess onAuthRefreshSuccess  etc ..)have to be set before the call to the init function.

Answer (score 0):

In standard flow I noticed that Token expiration is coming form Access Token Lifespan and Refresh Token expiration from SSO Session Idle. And it is recommended that Access Token Lifespan should be shorter then SSO time out. Should it be the other way around?
Also Access Token Lifespan can be overwritten in Clients Settings tab under Advanced Settings.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at our Angular sample app https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/demo-template/angular-product-app/src/main/webapp/js/app.js ? It could give you some tips maybe.

Comment: i am using same thing, it does not solve my purpose, actually it is not refreshing the token at all.